# Using at.js for '@mentions' -- can't display first/last name

Tags: javascript, meteor, mention

I'm using the at.js '@who mentions'(https://github.com/ichord/At.js) in my Meteor chat application, and would like to do the following:

Display 'username: firstName lastName' in the @who list.

It's currently displaying username only.

The mongo collection stores the firstName in profile.firstName, lastName in profile.lastName

Current code in channel.js:

```
setTimeout(function () {
          var dbUsers = Meteor.users.find({_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()}}).fetch();
          var users = _.sortBy(dbUsers, 'username');
          users = _.pluck(users, 'username');
          self.$('textarea[name=message]').atwho({
            at: '@',
            data: users,
          }).on('shown.atwho', function(event) {
            setIsMentioning(true);
          }).on('hidden.atwho', function(event) {
            setTimeout(function() { setIsMentioning(false); }, 100);
          });
        }, 500);
```

My new code in channel.js:

```
setTimeout(function () {
      var dbUsers = Meteor.users.find({_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()}}).fetch();
      var users = _.map(dbUsers, function(user) { return _.pick(user, 'username', 'profile.firstName', 'profile.lastName'); });
      self.$('textarea[name=message]').atwho({
        at: '@',
        data: users,
        displayTpl: '<li>${firstName} ${lastName}, ${degree}</li>',
        insertTpl: ':${username}:'
      }).on('shown.atwho', function(event) {
        setIsMentioning(true);
      }).on('hidden.atwho', function(event) {
        setTimeout(function() { setIsMentioning(false); }, 100);
      });
    }, 500);
```

Here's the publication for users in users.js:

```
Meteor.publish('users', function() {
  if(this.userId) { // We should only send data to logged in users.
    // filter by organization
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    if(user.profile && user.profile.organizationId)
      return Meteor.users.find(
        {'profile.organizationId': user.profile.organizationId},
        {fields: {'username': 1, 'emails': 1, 'status': 1, 'profile.firstName': 1, 'profile.lastName': 1}}
      );
    else
      return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'username': 1, 'emails': 1, 'status': 1}});
  }

  this.ready();
});
```

Here's the users subscription in routes.js:

```
teamRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
  prefix: '/teams/:team',
  middlewares: [AccountsTemplates.ensureSignedIn],
  subscriptions: function(params) {
    this.register('teamChannels', Meteor.subscribe('teamChannels', params.team));
    this.register('teamDirectChannels', Meteor.subscribe('teamDirectChannels', params.team));
    this.register('users', Meteor.subscribe('users', params.team));
    this.register('teams', Meteor.subscribe('myTeams'));
    this.register('reads', Meteor.subscribe('reads'));
    this.register('mentions', Meteor.subscribe('mentions'));
  }
});
```

Would really appreciate anyone who can explain to me what I'm doing wrong! Thanks so much.